# mapkit map doesn't reload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

hi guys hope this is a simple question.

I have a navigationController with mapkit. How do i reload the pinpoints/data when I pressed back and select another option?

This is the scenario: I have a main page of table of patients objects. When i press on an unique row, it is suppose to be to populate points on the next page (mapkit). However, when i pressed back and select another patient object, it will always return the same mapkit view which patient object i have first selected.... really puzzling... the mapkit doesnt reload at all..

Hope someone can help or guide me=) Please help guys... viewDidLoad method only load once.. and viewWillAppear method create layers.... =(

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.region.center animated:NO];
```

Comment: @simon.. thanks for the prompt reply.. but under which method do i implement this? 

Many thanks